# Shiny - plot with renderUI not display in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i just new in Shiny and i have a problem in shiny. i have a plot but the plot not display in shiny. and no message error.this is the code...

UI

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(

     uiOutput("scatter")

               ))
  )
```

server

```
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$scatter <- renderUI({
    datax <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6,1)
    datay <- matrix(c(1,7,6,4,5,3),6,1)
    titleplot<-"title"
    summary <- "testing text"

    pl <- plot(datax, datay, main = titleplot, xlab = "input$axis1", ylab = "input$axis2", pch=18, col="blue") 

    list(
    pl,
    summary
    )


    })

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually you also can use uiOutput, and it is very useful sometimes, because you can create a user interface from the server side. This is the solution:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("scatter")
    ))
)


server = function(input, output) {

  output$scatter <- renderUI({
    datax <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6,1)
    datay <- matrix(c(1,7,6,4,5,3),6,1)
    titleplot<-"title"
    summary <- "testing text"


    output$plot_test <- renderPlot({
      pl <- plot(datax, datay, main = titleplot, xlab = "input$axis1", ylab = "input$axis2", pch=18, col="blue") 
    })

    plotOutput("plot_test")

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `renderUI` function in `server` to `renderPlot` while `uiOutput` to `plotOutput` in `ui` correspondingly.

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),
        mainPanel(

            plotOutput("scatter")

        ))
)

server = function(input, output) {

    output$scatter <- renderPlot({
        datax <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),6,1)
        datay <- matrix(c(1,7,6,4,5,3),6,1)
        titleplot<-"title"
        summary <- "testing text"

        pl <- plot(datax, datay, main = titleplot, xlab = "input$axis1", ylab = "input$axis2", pch=18, col="blue") 

        list(
            pl,
            summary
        )


    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: the "testing text" not display,

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign seperate `output` slots for the plot and the text. That is because shiny uses different (css) classes for each of tose render functions. The following code should do what you want.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatter"),
      textOutput("testingText")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    datax <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 6, 1)
    datay <- matrix(c(1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3), 6, 1)
    titleplot <- "title"
    plot(datax, datay, main = titleplot, xlab = "input$axis1", 
      ylab = "input$axis2", pch = 18, col = "blue") 
  })

  output$testingText <- renderText({
    "testing text"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

*Additional note*: The line

```
pl <- plot( ... )
```

does not make sense. In `R`, plots can not be saved as objects. `ggplots` are an exception, but you would still have to use `renderPlot` to display a `ggplot` object in `shiny`.